# Как вывести элемент из словаря по его индексу как если бы в массиве?

Tags: python

У меня есть словарь

```py
disciplines = {
    "mathAnalysis_lecture": "...",
    "mathAnalysis_practice": "...",
    "probabilityTheory_practice": "...",
    "introToSE_lecture": "...",
    "introToSE_practice": "..."
}
```

Можно ли достать элемент с ключом `introToSE_lecture` , только не по ключю, а по его индексу`(3)`? Или это вообще глупо и стоит использоваться массивы?

Comment: Глупо и стоит использовать массивы)

Comment: А какая цель? dict - не является упорядоченной коллекцией. Его значения возможно получить с помощью dict.values() и привести к списку/кортежу, но -— зачем?

Comment: @Tihon уже является

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Вариант для Python 3.6 и моложе

Начиная с Python 3.6 в канонической реализации Python порядок добавления элементов в словарь сохраняется. То есть итератор `items()` возвращает элементы в том порядке, в котором они были добавлены.

Если у вас **гарантированно** используется Python 3.6+, то вы можете использовать вот такую функцию (неоптимизировано!)

```
def nth_discipline(pos):
    "Возвращает пару (название, описание) из словаря disciplines для курса на n-ной позиции."
    items = list(disciplines.items())
    return items[pos]
```

## Вариант универсальный

Практически с самого начала в Python был специальный тип [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), который сохранял порядок добавления.

Поэтому если вы не уверены в том, на какой версии Python будет исполняться ваш код, то лучше воспользоваться им:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

disciplines = OrderedDict([
    ("mathAnalysis_lecture", "MAL"),
    ("mathAnalysis_practice", "MAP"),
    ("probabilityTheory_practice", "PTP"),
    ("introToSE_lecture", "ISE_L"),
    ("introToSE_practice", "ISE_P")
])
```

Правда, ни `keys`, ни `items`, ни `values` для `OrderedDict` не поддерживают взятие элемента по индексу. Поэтому даже для `OrderedDict` нужна функция `nth_discipline`. Просто в случае `OrderedDict` она на всех реализациях Python будет давать правильный результат.